# Codeigniter: Join between three tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to do a Join between three tables, in which in one table could not be informations to do the join.

This my tables:

**Meetings**

- id
- docent_id
- motivation

**Persons**

- id
- name
- surname

**Companions**

- id
- meeting_id
- name
- surname

Now I want to recover the information where Meetings.docent_id = Persons.id (and this is ok), I want also recover information where Meetings.id = Companions.meeting_id, and if I add this condition I receive an error.

The problem is that last condition is not always present, because the user can decide if he wants companion or not, (So in case it doesn't want it they aren't written to the Companions table) so it could be that some Meetings.id doesn't have a correspondence in Companions.meeting_id.

I have tried a code like:

```
 $query = $this->db->select('Meetings.*, Persons.name, Persons.surname, Companions.*')
            ->from('Meetings')
            ->join('Companions', 'Meetings.id = Companions.meeting_id', 'LEFT')
            ->join('Persons', 'Meetings.docent_id = Persons.id', 'INNER')
            ->where('delete_date is null')
           //....
```

And it returns me a 500 errors, I think because some meetings don't have Companions. How can I do to obtain all meetings and if there are companions show them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->select('Meetings.*, Persons.name, Persons.surname, Companions.*')
        ->from('Meetings')
        ->join('Companions', 'Meetings.id = Companions.meeting_id', 'LEFT')
        ->join('Persons', 'Meetings.docent_id = Persons.id', 'INNER')
        ->where('Persons.delete_date is null')
```

be sure you have fully qualified  column name for the where (could be you have the same column name in two table joined)

Comment: I have tried before to insert LEFT the INNER Join but I receive the error anyway.

Comment: are you sure the error  500 is related  to the query code  ..or is related  on some others part of code ? .. check the exact error message  in your server log

Comment: Yes because if I leave this condition: `->join('Companions', 'Meetings.id = Companions.meeting_id', 'INNER')` it works

Comment: answer  updated  with a suggestion for fully qualified  column in where clause

Comment: Ok now I don't have the error. But it filters me only the field that have a correspondence in the Companions table.

Comment: Mmmh it doesn't work correctly, now I have all meetings that I search, but some informations are null. Like meeting.id :(

maybe the problem could be that Companions and Persons have field with the same name?

Comment: This is the left join behaviour  .. or you have only the matching row or you have all rows ..  anyway  ..  this mean that you have not more the error  ..so  my answer  should resolve your orginal question  .. (i'm not in your data and your logic)